# Page links are broken in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Inside the dashboard of WordPress, there's a section called permalink.
I would like to change the settings to "POST NAME" instead of "DEFAULT".
When i save changes and visit the website, none of the page link (TAB) works.

This is the message that pops up in the browser.

Not Found
The requested URL /site/example_page/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

I need help as soon as possible.

Comment: make sure the .htaccess file is updated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. It is more suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How did you get on with this Nechar? Did you solve the issue you were having?

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me today, it was down to me not copying the .htaccess file because it was hidden ( I was using MAMP, and Mac OS X ).

Make sure you have the .htaccess file in the root directory of your Wordpress installation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your permalink settings, and re-save them a couple of times. Sometimes, the server cache's the settings and re-saving will flush it out.